# Convert oracle sql to hana sql

Tags: sql, hana, regexp-like

I have a where condition in oracle SQL 11g which I want to use in SAP HANA SQL :
Oracle SQL query :

```
NOT  REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(substr(GEN_ID,4,5)), '[A-Z]')
```

I have tried using like_regexp but unable to fetch records.

```
NOT  REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER(substr(GEN_ID,4,5)), '[A-Z]')
```

I am expecting the regexp_like to work same in HANA

Answer (score 0):

try [`LIKE_REGEXPR`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/b40d483dd34d47aa9cc89b4d8a6e617e.html)

```
UPPER(substring(GEN_ID,4,5)) LIKE_REGEXPR  '[A-Z]'
```

Comment: It is pointing syntax error at 51 near '[A-z]'  .. Is there some other way ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In either database, I think I would phrase this as:

```
GEN_ID LIKE_REGEXP '^.{3}[^A-Za-z]{5}'
```

I find that doing part of the string matching using substrings and `not` and part using regular expressions is more complicated than necessary.